# Archive Direct Messages from Twitter

Tags: api, twitter, message

Is there any way to download the own direct messages to archive them?

The [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/direct_messages) limits the call to the latest 200 DMs, which cannot download a full archive for longer conversations.

The [official Twitter Archive](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170160?lang=en) seems not to contain the messages at all. And most thirdparty services (which you might not want to let them access your messages anyway) will be using the api and the best they can do is to poll often enough not to miss the 200 DM limit.

Is there any other way to get the messages from twitter? Scrolling back on the site seems to work, but they always load older messages in small steps and copy&paste from there gives an rather ugly result, too.

It does not need to full twitter-api information, just handle, time and message (maybe media links, if possible) should be available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have created a [tool](https://github.com/Mincka/DMArchiver) (https://github.com/Mincka/DMArchiver) to download my direct messages, with the ability to also download the uploaded images, videos and GIFs (as MP4).

Because it does not rely on the API, it is possible to download more than 200 messages. The script just simulate the "scrolling method" described by dimethylarginine and parse the result.

The main idea is to make requests in loop by calling the following URL with a valid `auth_token` cookie value for the authentication and parse the json response:
https://twitter.com/messages/with/conversation?id=1337&max_entry_id=1337

The `max_entry_id` value is not required for the first request. You need to use the value of the `min_entry_id` variable in the response as the new `max_entry_id` in each subsequent iteration to get the next 20 older tweets. When `max_entry_id` is not in the json response, you are at the begin of the thread.

Some headers are also required to get a proper response from Twitter:

```
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0'
'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01'
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

Currently, the output of the tool is only available as an *IRC-like* conversation but I may add other output styles in the future (HTML, JSON, XML...).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13932811)

Comment: Post updated with the algorithm and headers requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to bring this thread back to life, but I've been having a look at this too. There are no third-party apps that can do this (as far as I'm aware) but having had a look at the source code of Twitter, it seems like with some fiddling I MIGHT be able to get them downloaded. My 'research' has shown that when you scroll up, it uses JS to load the tweets above it, using a call similar to the API. If you look through Chrome's network log you should be able to see where it gets called and the URL of the call. One can't access this through a browser, but I'll let you know if I get any further.

Sorry this isn't much of an answer yet - I'm just posting this so I can update it and not forget to do it.

Update - 10/05/2016 - I've managed to download all of my Twitter DMs. It is not elegant AT ALL, but it works. It involves leaving your computer on overnight, with the middle mouse button clicked to scroll up your DMs. Once theat has been done (it's reached the first DM), you can download the webpage and with it your DMs. This uses a lot of memory, so be careful! I am working on parsing the HTML now so it is more readable the the soup it is currently.

Comment: I did the same. I guess you could observe the url generation (the ids seem to be included in the html), export the cookies and then download the messages in chunks by parsing the html, extracting the oldest id and generating a url downloading messages with lower id.
If you want to experiment, firefox developer tools have an option "copy curl commandline", which adds useragent, cookies, referer, post-data, etc to the command line to reproduce the request.